# How to check text inputs in textarea and press submit button accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a button and a textarea which is enclosed in div 
tag.

If I click on the button, following things would happen

1. button type and value attributes will change to 'Submit' and some 
   other name
2. the div enclosed text area will appear and disappear in a toggled 
   manner.

above points 1 and 2 have been implemented.

But I am having problem to implement the following points :

1. The changed submit button will only submit the page if it detects 
   some text has been written in the text area
2. Otherwise, the submit button would change to the normal button and 
   hide the text area.

   ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.
         min.js">  
        
        Hello

   ```
   <div style="border: 5px solid #A9A9A9;" id="hidden_area">
   <table>
   <tr bgcolor=#CCCCEE align=center>

   <th>Text area</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>
   <textarea name="field" rows=5 cols=40 style="font-size: small"></textarea>
   </td>       
   </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   ```

This is add.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#changeText").click(function(e){
        $(this).attr('type','submit').attr('id', 'enter').val('Enter Text')
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#hidden_area").toggle()
        });

})
```

Comment: Please, add relevant code in question itself

Comment: There is a reason you weren't able to insert fiddle link without displaying code in the question. We shouldn't have to go to external site to see it, questions should be self contained

Comment: check text area content (value) length and if > 0 submit else hide

Answer (score 0):

Just need to check which state the button is in and the content of the textarea. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#hidden_area").hide();
 $("#changeText").click(function(e){

     if ($(this).attr('type') == 'button') {
        $(this).attr('type','submit').attr('id', 'enter').val('Enter Text');
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#hidden_area").toggle();
    } else if ($("#hidden_area textarea[name='field']").val().trim() !== '') {
        alert('submitting');
    } else {
        $("#hidden_area").toggle();
        $(this).attr('type','button').attr('changeText', 'enter').val('Click');;
    }
 });

});
```

See [this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/dwvLmtn3/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do it:

```
$("#changeText").click(function(e){
    $(this).attr('type','submit').attr('id', 'enter').val('Enter Text');

    var txt = $('textarea').val();
    if ( $.trim(txt) != '' ){
        alert('Submit page here');
    }else{
        $(this).attr('type','button').attr('id', 'changeText').val('click');
        $("#hidden_area").toggle()
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jh58dycf/4/)</kbd>